# Using Domain name in EULA of a software rather than my name in the Licensor field

Tags: licensing, websites, user-experience, eula

I intend to sell a software solution. I have already registered a domain but I don't have a registered company. Can I use my website/domain name (eg:myproduct.com) for the licensor field in the EULA rather than using my name?

I will renew my domain yearly if there is a problem with this. Do you know any software companies that work like this?

I'm confused about the users point of view will they find it a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

The usual IANAL applies - for legal advice, consult a lawyer.

That said, my understanding is that a domain name or a website are not themselves legal persons, and thus cannot close any legally binding agreements. Natural persons and corporations can, and the way these things are usually done is by defining the domain name or website URL as the legal person closing the agreement in the first section of the agreement - something like this:

> John Doe, Example Way 15, Someplace 12345 ('example.com') and ***_*__*_*** ('licensee') hereby agree upon the following: ...

In any case, EULA's are legally tricky, especially if you consider that multiple countries with conflicting laws may be involved, so if the EULA is vital to you, by all means spend some money on actual legal consult.

Answer (score 1):

You say "registered company", so you're not here in the USA, where we have corporations, LLCs, partnerships, doing-business-as ("DBAs"), *etc*.  Most places where there are registered companies are British Commonwealth countries, where there is usually some organization like the UK's Companies House that is the registrar.  Such places have very strict laws about doing business in your own name or a registered name.

Short answer, you probably shouldn't do this.  Long answer, contact the local equivalent of a lawyer for advice, not a bunch of programmers :-)